# How i can assign /32 ip address to openstack nova instance without float ip?

Tags: openstack, openvswitch, openstack-neutron, dhcp-option, ovn

I'm developing a custom panel for my openstack home lab via rest api.
I've investigated [Hetzner](https://console.hetzner.cloud/) cloud ip (v4) addressing mechanism and i found it is like this:

[image]

It is assigning /32 valid ip v4 address and routing via invalid ip for preventing ip wasting.
Is this possible to implement using neutron?
I've read about `dhcp options` in `ovn` but i'm not sure.

( the valid ip address in the picture is not assigned to any server )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to set dhcp-options on each port using `neutron`

```
neutron port-update p1 --extra-dhcp-opt opt_name=netmask,opt_value=255.255.255.255
neutron port-update p1 --extra-dhcp-opt opt_name=classless-static-route,opt_value="192.168.121.121"
```

And for Windows machines:

```
neutron port-update p1 --extra-dhcp-opt opt_name=ms-classless-static-route,opt_value="192.168.121.121"
```